# 'PTX JIT compilation failed' from cuModuleLoadData

Tags: multithreading, cuda

Below is the code:

```
#define FILENAME "kernel.code"
#define kernel_name "hello_world"
#define THREADS 4

std::vector<char> load_file()
{
    std::ifstream file(FILENAME, std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
    std::streamsize fsize = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    std::vector<char> buffer(fsize);
    if (!file.read(buffer.data(), fsize)) {
        failed("could not open code object '%s'\n", FILENAME);
    }
    return buffer;
}

struct joinable_thread : std::thread
{
    template <class... Xs>
    joinable_thread(Xs&&... xs) : std::thread(std::forward<Xs>(xs)...) // NOLINT
    {
    }

    joinable_thread& operator=(joinable_thread&& other) = default;
    joinable_thread(joinable_thread&& other)            = default;

    ~joinable_thread()
    {
        if(this->joinable())
            this->join();
    }
};

void run(const std::vector<char>& buffer) {

    CUdevice device;
    CUDACHECK(cuDeviceGet(&device, 0));
    CUcontext context;
    CUDACHECK(cuCtxCreate(&context, 0, device));

    CUmodule Module;

    CUDACHECK(cuModuleLoadData(&Module, &buffer[0]));

    ...

}

void run_multi_threads(uint32_t n) {

    {
        auto buffer = load_file();
        std::vector<joinable_thread> threads;
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            threads.emplace_back(std::thread{[&, i, buffer] {                
                  run(buffer);
            }});
        }
    }
}

int main() {

    CUDACHECK(cuInit(0));

    run_multi_threads(THREADS);

}
```

And the code kernel.cu used for ptx is as follows:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"

extern "C" __global__ void hello_world(float* a, float* b) {
    int tx = threadIdx.x;
    b[tx] = a[tx];
}
```

I m generating the ptx in this way
nvcc --ptx kernel.cu -o kernel.code

Im using a machine with GeForce GTX TITAN X.

And Im facing this "PTX JIT compilation failed" from cuModuleLoadData error, only when I m trying to use this with multiple threads. If i remove the multi-threading part and run normally, this error doesn't occur.

Can anyone please tell me what is going wrong and how to overcome this.

Comment: What happens if THREADS is set to 1?

Comment: Same error occurs even if its set to 1.  Only if i remove threads and use normally, it is working fine.  I hope its not with ptx kernel.code, as it works without threads.

Comment: Are you sure your file I/O which loads the code is thread safe?

Comment: Yes, as the load file is done before the thread launch and passing only the buffer to all the threads.  But surprisingly,  if i move that buffer = load_file() to the main and then pass buffer to run_multi_threads, I don't see the error. It is working. For now I m fine that it works, but still i doubt why it shouldn't work with the original code, as file load is not done in threads.

Comment: So the problem was actually in passing an invalid buffer to the JIT, not anything to do with the code itself. Do you want to add a short answer to get this off the unanswered question list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, I was able to get it to work by moving the load_file() call to the main, so that the buffer read from the file is valid, and then pass only the buffer to all the threads.

Answer (score 0):

Actually in the original code, the buffer will be deconstructed once it leaves the '{...}' scope. So when thread starts, you may read the invalid buffer.

If you put your buffer in the main, it will not be deconstructed or freed until the program exits.

So yes, it's because you pass the invalid buffer (which may have already been freed) to the cu code.